# Can a HTTP client use chunked encoding to send data to a HTTP server?

Tags: http, encoding, client, chunked

Everything that I have come across shows the HTTP server sending a response back using chunked encoding but is it possible for the client to send data (ie upload a file) in a POST request that is chunked? If so, does the server have to be specifically configured to handle this kind of request?

Comment: chunked encoding presumes that you know details about the size and offset of the chunks you want. Servers will know nothing about the file you're uploading, so chunks make no sense.

Comment: would it not make sense in the situation where the file you are uploading is not whole yet? For example say I am downloading a large video file and I want to be able to upload it to a server as it is downloading

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, but no, not all servers support it.